# /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash doest exist

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to everybody

I have installed debian squeeze and I follow ROS Electric installation instructions

I do the following:

1.-# apt-get install build-essential python-yaml cmake subversion wget python-setuptools mercurial

2.-# easy_install -U rosinstall

3.-# rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

4.- # source ~/ros/setup.bash

I can see that /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash doest exist /op/ is empty. And, I can not create a bash script for configuring your ROS workspace environment.

Any ideas? I have no clue, I will aprreciate any help.

Regards,

Alfredo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11866//opt/ros/electric/setup.bash-doest-exist/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the rosinstall command as above, everything is installed in ~/ros. So instead of using /opt/ros/electric, using ~/ros should get you going.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-11-09**:
#!/bin/sh
source ~/ros/setup.bash
export ROS_ROOT=~/ros
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src:$PYTHONPATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2011-11-08**:
I am still a bit confuse. The question is now, how a bash script to configure a work space environment shall be?  as stated in the tutorial                                                                                                                                                                                        http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-11-08**:
The tutorials are mainly written assuming the default Ubuntu installation, which installs in /opt/ros/electric. As you are using Debian and build ROS from source, the installation directory is different in your case. So yes, in your case it's "source ~/ros/setup.bash"

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2011-11-08**:
I see, well, why the tutorial points to "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash"  for the script for the ROS workspace environment.  it shall be I guess "source ~/ros/setup.bash" for the script, right?